# Reversing HTMl table value to ruby variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I am working On ROR app , I am first generating table from ruby variable in views . Variable is this :

```
h=[{"folder"=>"test3", "weight"=>"100.0", "stocks"=>[{"id"=>"stock id3", "name"=>"Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"55.8"}, {"id"=>"stock id4", "name"=>"Power Finance Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"44.2"}]},{"folder"=>"test", "weight"=>"100.0", "stocks"=>[{"id"=>"stock id3", "name"=>"Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"55.8"}, {"id"=>"stock id4", "name"=>"Power Finance Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"44.2"}]},{"folder"=>"test2", "weight"=>"100.0", "stocks"=>[{"id"=>"stock id3", "name"=>"Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"55.8"}, {"id"=>"stock id4", "name"=>"Power Finance Corporation Ltd.", "weight"=>"44.2"}]}]
```

Now This is how table is getting generated :

```
<h1 align="center"> Current Portfolio </h1>
 <table id="portfolios" width="500" border="1" align="center" height="300">
<thead class="colHeaders">
    <tr><th class="weight" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Weight in Motif </h3></th>
        <th class="name" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Segment &amp; Stocks</h3></th>
        <th class="price" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Name of stock </h3></th>
  </thead>

<% h.each do |stock| %>
<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  <%= stock["weight"] %> </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   <%= stock["folder"] %> </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
  </tr>

  <% stock["stocks"].each do |details| %>
      <tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    <%= details["weight"] %> </th>
        <th>    <%= details["id"] %> </th>
        <% a=details["name"] %>
        <% a.gsub! /\s+/, '-' %>
        <% str="www.dalal-street.in/" %>
        <% str=str +a %>
        <% str=str[0..-2] %>
        <td id="<%= details["name"] %>">
            <%= link_to h(details["name"]), str %> 
            </td>


   </tr>


   <% end %>
   <% end %>

 </table>
```

Using jquery i am changing stocks position using drag and drop. i.e is stock id 3 from folder test 3 to test . Now i need to update this into my backhand. Is there any way I can get my h variable updated with the new value according to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do send your entire table variable back to rails, you need the following:

---

A/ build the table object on the client side with javascript in order to collect the current state of the table after modification. (if the kind of modifications we are talking about get complex you could be interested in front-end js frameworks like [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) or [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/)).

=> 1. you show the table as is on a path like

```
     "/table/table_id" or "/table/table_id/edit"
```

=> 2. it is modified by the user

=> 3. the user clicks on a button or whatsoever to 'save' the table to the server

=> 4. you collect the data of the modified table using jQuery or any framework in the user's browser

---

B/ sending this front-end variable containing your table after modification to the backend via a POST request to an update method on rails side.

=> 5. you send it back as an argument to the server by making a POST request to the server, let's say at the url

```
     "/table/table_id/update"
```

with post_data being

```
      {table: your_modified_table_object_as_json}
```

---

C/ processing the sent data on the server side and saving it.

=> 6. in your rails controller that contains the 'show' action rendering the table and instantiating the variable, add an update method with a corresponding route answering the url where the js POST the table data

=> 7. in this update method put the necessary processing needed to parse the table sent by your frontend js POST request and save it. Depending on your rails app data structure, you may need to parse the sent data

example

```
    def update
      @table = Table.find(params[:id])
      updated_table = JSON.parse(params[:table])
      @table.update_with_table_data(updated_table) # method to be implemented in Table model
      ... response, etc
    end
```

---

#### EDIT: Additional info

To get the id of the table and send data back to the server you should use one of these two methods

---

1) Use conventional routing:

In that case the url on which you serve the table and the user is to modify it contain the id of the table. It should be something like the following

```
    # browser window current url
    /tables/TABLEID
    or 
    /tables/TABLEID/edit
```

So that you could just get the url by calling window.location.href in javascript

```
    # js
    current_url = window.location.href
```

And then use it to send back the data

```
    #js
    update_url = current_url.replace(/\/edit$/, '')
    update_method = 'PUT'
    jQuery.ajax( url: update_url
                 method: update_method
                 ...
```

On Rails side your route would be set to give you the id inside the params hash

---

2) Other solution: put the id or directly the entire path inside an html attribute and retrieve it from javascript

Example:

You would add this attribute to your table url for example:

```
    <table update_path="/tables/#{TABLEID}" id='table'>
    ... your table
    </table>
```

And then in your javascript

```
    update_url = jQuery('#table').attr('update_path')
    ...
```

---

For a more detailed answer on the Javascript side processing of the table, see:
[How to deduce changing table variable using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420151/how-to-deduce-changing-table-variable-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you tell me how i can use jquery to get table id and deduce variable from it. I am novice in frontend.

Comment: Hey thanks but i don't need this much stuff see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420151/how-to-deduce-changing-table-varaiable-using-jquery , if you could help with this i will figure out rest.

Comment: There is only one table.

Comment: Hi Deepender Singla, I've answered your question for the js side of this on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420151/how-to-deduce-changing-table-variable-using-jquery/18428062#18428062

Comment: I think my answer here actually answers your question for the integration of this with Rails. Could you please accept my answers both here and on your js question ?