# How to deduce changing table variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table HTML code :

```
<table id="portfolios" width="500" border="1" align="center" height="300">
<thead class="colHeaders">
    <tr><th class="weight" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Weight in Motif </h3></th>
        <th class="name" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Segment &amp; Stocks</h3></th>
        <th class="price" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Name of stock </h3></th>
</thead>

<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test3 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test2 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>
```

and this also:

```
<table id="portfolios" width="500" border="1" align="center" height="300">
<thead class="colHeaders">
    <tr><th class="weight" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Weight in Motif </h3></th>
        <th class="name" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Segment &amp; Stocks</h3></th>
        <th class="price" bgcolor="#999999"><h4> Name of stock </h3></th>
</thead>

<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test3 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="titles" value="Disable Sort"> 
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>  100.0 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>   test2 </th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <h5>    </th>
</tr>

<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    55.8 </th>
        <th>    stock id3 </th>
        <td id="Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd">Indian-Oil-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>


<tr id="Stocks">
        <th>    44.2 </th>
        <th>    stock id4 </th>
        <td id="Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.">
            <a href="www.dalal-street.in/Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd">Power-Finance-Corporation-Ltd.</a> 
            </td>


</tr>
```

Basically both of this are generated HTML code from erb file.Now in first code variable used is this :

```
h=[ { "folder"  => "test3", 
      "weight"  => "100.0", 
      "stocks"  => [{ "id"     => "stock id3", 
                      "name"   => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.", 
                      "weight" => "55.8"}, 
                    { "id"     => "stock id4", 
                      "name"   => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.", 
                      "weight" => "44.2" }
                  ]},
    { "folder"   => "test",
      "weight"   => "100.0",
      "stocks"   => [{ "id"    => "stock id3",
                       "name"  => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.",
                       "weight"=> "55.8"},
                      {"id"    => "stock id4",
                       "name"  => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.",
                       "weight"=> "44.2"}]
     },
    { "folder"   => "test2",
      "weight"   => "100.0",
      "stocks"   => [{ "id"    => "stock id3",
                       "name"  => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.",
                       "weight"=> "55.8"}, 
                      {"id"    => "stock id4",
                       "name"  => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.",
                       "weight"=> "44.2"
                      }]
     }
  ]
```

Whereas in thse second code I created the table is changed using drag and drop , Now how i can get an updated h variable which will be this :

```
h=[ { "folder"  =>  "test3",
      "weight"  =>  "100.0",
      "stocks"  => [{"id"      => "stock id3",
                     "name"    => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "55.8"},
                    {"id"      => "stock id4",
                     "name"    => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "44.2"},
                    {"id"      => "stock id3",
                     "name"    => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "55.8"},
                    {"id"      => "stock id4",
                     "name"    => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "44.2"},
                    {"id"      => "stock id3",
                     "name"    => "Indian Oil Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "55.8"},
                    {"id"      => "stock id4",
                     "name"    => "Power Finance Corporation Ltd.",
                     "weight"  => "44.2"}]
    },
    { "folder" =>  "test",
      "weight" =>  "100.0",
      "stocks" =>  [],
    { "folder" =>  "test2",
      "weight" =>  "100.0",
      "stocks" =>  []
    }
 ]
```

using Javascript or something else (APP is ruby on rails ). I am completely unaware of javascript plz give a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do something like this.

```
(function ($) {

  retrieveTable = function () {
      // define an output table variable
      var h = [];
      // and an empty variable for the current folder
      var current_folder = {};

      // define tables that contain the keys for your values inside the table
      keys = {
          titles: ['weight', 'folder', 'stocks'],
          stocks: ['weight', 'id', 'name']
      };

      // select all rows in your table and iterate through them
      $('#portfolios tr').each(function (index, row) {
          // make sure you don't cacth the row in thead
          // (another solution would be to have an actual tbody 
          // and iterate over it directly $("#portfolios tbody tr"))
          if (!$(row).parents('thead').length > 0) {
              // check if the row is a title
              if ($(row).attr('id') == 'titles') {
                  // if it is a title, that means that we are in a new folder
                  // set the current_folder variable and add it to the table
                  current_folder = {};
                  h.push(current_folder);
                  // and fill it with the info from this first row
                  $(row).children('th').each(function (iindex,title) {
                      current_folder[keys.titles[iindex]] = cleanText($(title).text());
                  });
                  // define an array as the value for the 'stocks' key
                  current_folder['stocks'] = [];
              } else {
                  // if the 'tr' is not a 'titles', then it must be a 'Stocks'
                  // you can fill it with the info with the table
                  // before adding it to the current_folder['stocks'] array
                  current_stock = {};
                  // your 'th' correspond to weight and id and 'tr' to stock name
                  $(row).children('th, td').each(function (iindex,attribut) {
                      current_stock[keys.stocks[iindex]] = cleanText($(attribut).text());
                  });
                  // then you can add the stock to the 'stocks' array
                  current_folder['stocks'].push(current_stock);
              };
          };
      });
      return h;
  };

  cleanText = function (strg) {
      return strg.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Then when you have retrieved the retrieveTable() object, send it back to your Rails server, parse it as JSON to make it a ruby Hash => that gives you a table in the same format as the one from which you started, with modifications from your user on the client side.

For integration with the Rails side, see my answer to your first question here: 
[Reversing HTMl table value to ruby variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418465/reversing-html-table-value-to-ruby-variable/18419248#18419248)